# Converting 12-14 car battery voltage to 9v

Tags: power-supply, current, voltage-regulator

I am trying to install a small dehumidifier in the back of my car to help with defogging the back half of my vehicle.

The dehumidifier operates off of 9V at roughly 3 Amps.

I tried using a LM2596 but the IC ended up overheating. I have not tried and put a heatsink on it yet since I don't have one at the moment.

It seems that the dehumidifier operates ok at nearly 12 Volts but since a car battery can get up to 14 Volts, I'm scared to push the limit anymore.

Is there an easier and/or possibly more power efficient way of doing this?

Comment: There should not be that much moisture inside your car. I strongly suggest you put a desiccant inside such as calcium chloride flakes.

Comment: If you were worried about 14V, take a look at this automotive transients illustration: http://www.acrosser.com/eweb/uploadfile/20110510161138577.jpg

Comment: leave the windows closed when you run through the car wash

Comment: @jsotola and limit other moisture producing activities : breathing etc...

Comment: if your car has air con run it and the heater (on fresh, not recirculate) both at the same time, this will produce warm dry air faster than any small dehumidifier,

Comment: Where I live it rains a lot and the humidity is usually quite high. I've tested the air quality in my car with a humidity sensor and it read a high humidity level. I've also tested the dehumidifier in my car and it worked well enough to convince me to install one.

Comment: @Jasen this is a nice solution that I know of however my vehicle is very spacy and the AC does not pull enough humidity out of the back of the car.

Comment: maybe a fan would help.

Comment: If you are in a warm humid climate, you should get those plastic guards for the windows so you can leave them down just a bit all the time. This is what people in Hawaii use. This will cause the humidity inside and outside your car to be the same. If you live in a place where humidity is seasonal, I would suggest using a desiccant during the wet season.

Comment: But if you regularly see condensation on the INSIDE of your window, you definitely need to dry the car out inside thoroughly or you are going to have problems with mold and/or corrosion and/or odors.

Comment: Have you tried changing the pollen filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XL4015 is good for 3.5A the datasheet says 5A but that requires a big heat-sink).

However you really need an automotive rated DC-DC converter. 
Like the LM2596 (good for about 1.5A with only pcb heatsink) the XL4015 is not rated for automotive use, so it may not last well connected to a car's electrical system.

For an automotive rated DC-DC converter:

maybe this one.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/160W-8A-DC-DC/32828844593.html

Comment: This looks like a good part to use. If not, I know I'll find another use for it. Just ordered one. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up.. Just received the part and it works well beyond expectations with a efficiency of ~94% with my application.

Answer (score 4):

Linear voltage regulators are usually for low power applications. It will be very hard to find one that suits your problem.

I would suggest you look for a DC/DC converter(buck-converter, stepdown-converter). There are some pre-made kits out there that you can use. (I can't give you any link because I don't know where you live, but eBay, Amazon or Aliexpress will do the trick.)

These converters also operate a lot more efficiently than linear voltage regulators and are nowadays affordable to buy (10-15$ or euro).

In the unlikely case that you can't get hold of one, you can build a step-down converter yourself. The schematic is simple enough.

*** It's propably too early in the morning^^, so I made a foolish mistake, the LM2596 is of course already a DC/DC converter (was thinking of LM7809).

I looked at its specs right now, and it said 3 A max. You say your dehumidifier takes about three amps, so you would use your converter at maximum rating all the time, which is usually bad.

For the best result you should find a similar one with 4.5 A max or something like that.

Heatsink should work too, but in the end it doesn't change the fact that you are constantly pushing the converter to its max range.

Comment: LM2596 OP is using is a buck converter...

Comment: you're absolutely right :/ i was thinking about the lm7809 in an answer before.

Comment: All good advice though...

Answer (score 3):

Automotive supply voltage spikes are probably about the worst you can find in any piece of equipment or vehicle so whatever you decide to use as a buck converter you MUST protect it. For instance you can get 100 volt transients from a load dump: -

[image]

The picture was taken from [this article](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4240) by Maxim entitled "*Active High-Voltage Transient Protectors Trump Conventional Approaches in Automotive Electronics*".

It may surprise that you also need to protect against significant drops in voltage - think about what happens if the battery voltage dropped to 9 volts (for instance during turning the engine to start it); the full current of the output is then taken by the input and this may cause a problem for some boost converters: -

[image]

Maxim then go on to propose several ideas for protection using varistors and TVS devices culminating in a chip designed for the job: -

[image]

So, you need to take care about this problem or you may well end up with reliability issues or worse - at the very least you must fuse the wiring spur that feeds the buck regulator.

The LM2596 is rated for 40 volts on its input supply and this should be OK providing the protection methods mentioned above are also implemented but, as others have said, it's running out of steam trying to produce 9 volts at 3 amps.

Here's a contender (LTC7813) for higher powered applications. The design below shows a 5 volt output capable of 8 amps but you can adjust the voltage output to 9 volts easily.

[image]

It's probably a little over the top for your application because it has a "boost" section and this allows full operation even when cold cranking the engine.

Try googling "automotive buck voltage regulators". Maybe this one is better suited: -

[image]

The circuit above shows the input voltage range starting at 15 volts but, for a 9 volt output this can be as low as 11 volts with appropriate adjustments to RFB1 and RFB2.

This might be a useful consideration: -

[image]

You would need to set the two resistors that feed VFB to get a 9 volt output. The good thing about this chip is efficiency: -

[image]

Internal power loss is going to be about 1 watt when driving a load of 3 amps. The LM2596 is only going to be about 85% efficient compared to the above efficiency of about 95% i.e. a lot of heat comes from a design that uses the LM2596 despite it being a switching regulator.

Answer (score -2):

1. 36 W is a joke for de-humidifying something the size of a car.

   Of course a linear regulator is going to get hot.  Do the math.  At 13.6 V (normal battery voltage when the car is running) and 9 V out, the linear regulator drops 4.6 V.  That times the 3 A current is 13.8 W, which is how much power it will dissipate as heat.  That's way past what even a large transistor can handle without a heatsink.

   Use a *buck regulator*.  That is a type of switching power supply that reduces the input voltage.  Unlike linear regulators where the input current equals the output current, with a switcher the input *power* equals the output power (plus a little for inefficiency).

   For example, let's say you get a buck switcher that is 90% efficient.  Its output power is (9 V)(3 A) = 36 W.  That means its input power is (36 W)/90% = 40 W.  The switcher will dissipate 4 W as heat.  That probably still requires a heat sink, but the whole circuit can be smaller and cheaper than just the heat sink of the linear solution.

   Make sure whatever regulator you use can handle the high voltage spikes that are present on a car 12 V line.  These can be 10s of V above the nominal.  Either protect the input, or use a regulator specifically rated for automobile use.

   If you're really stuck on the de-humidifier concept, get one that runs on 12 V car power.

Comment: Clearly you didn't read my question. LM2596 is a switching buck converter. It is not a linear regulator. According to the datasheet, the way I had it wired up ran at about 83% efficiency.

Comment: @Mark: I just read your question again, and still don't see anything that says what a LM2596 is, nor a link to its datasheet.  You really can't expect everyone to know the part you happened to pick.  In any case, all this changes is that point 2 doesn't apply to your case, although it is still correct.  You need to re-read the answer again, especially point 3.  Even with 90% efficiency, you get 4 W dissipation.  Plug in your actual efficiency of 83%, and it should be blatantly clear that a heatsink is needed.  That's your problem, but don't forget about point 4.

Comment: So if I said LM7805; you think that I should need to include a datasheet? They are both very common electronic ICs.

Comment: @Mar: The 7805 is way more well known than the LM2596.  That doesn't mean saying *"... 7805 linear regulator ..."* the first time you mention it would be a bad thing.